# Basic CSS Positioning with Leaflet Map and HTML Table with React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having problems getting an HTML Table (made into a react component) to be on the right hand of the screen. The main problem is that the map has to have an position absolute. I usually don't work much with CSS and when I do everything is relative. I am pretty sure I am just messing something up basic in CSS or maybe it is a React.js thing. Here is the CSS Styling:

```
 <!-- styling - put in another file later -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .map {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 75%;
      float: left;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .table {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      float: right;
      width: 25%;
      z-index: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

and the basics body layout with div's that are attached to React Components (except the wrapper, which does not have a react component).

```
  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <div id='table'></div>
  </div>
```

And here is the react code for reference:

```
/* will go in main.jsx */
var reactComponentMap = React.renderComponent(
  <Map data={testJSON}/>,
  document.getElementById('map'),
  function() {
    // Map Component Callback
  }
);

var reactComponentTable = React.renderComponent(
  <Table />,
  document.getElementById('table'),
  function() {
    //Table Component Callback
  }
);
```

Here is my current output when making it with the above CSS code:
[image: Incorrect CSS Styling]

You can see above the table is over the map. The blank side to the right is the 25% reserved for the table, but it does not place it there. The map does only take up 75% of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is just a HTML/CSS problem. You confound classes and IDs. In your HTML you use IDs (id="table") and in your CSS-File you use classes (.table).

Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="map">Map</div>
    <div class="table">Table</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupid error. Use the correct "selector" for classes use "." and ids use "#" in CSS.